# Scanf save the new line in memory and reassignment

Tags: c

I put the code below (I don't have permission to upload picture so I put it in a link). Because when I enter a character I need to hit the enter key, the enter is saved in the memory and run the loop twice. I tried to put continue and hoped this will "clean the memory". Any suggestion how to do this with scanf? (I don't want to use other functions).

And second question - when I wrote the function in the begining, I passed variable that declare in the main function. I saw that I can reassign his value inside the function so I change to "return choose" and I will asssign this to the variable. My question is: why I can reassign value inside loop that in the main? Because I put the loop is the main and declared the variable in the main?

```
char continuePlaying()
{
    char choose[];
    printf("Do you want to continue playing? please choose Y or X: \n");
    scanf("%c", &choose);
    while(choose != 'Y' && choose != 'X')
    {
        printf("You entered wrong option. please choose Y or X: \n");
        scanf("%c", &choose);
    }

    return choose;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to provide the code as text instead of an image. You might want to read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Prefer to use `fgets()` for user input.

Comment: Please assume that I am blind and that my screenreader cannot handle your link to a picture of text.

Comment: Some people have a C compiler that has images as input

Comment: Thanks for the answers. About the fgets() - I am going to read about this function. I am beginner and not known this function. Is there option to do this without using another function?

About the code, I tried to put my code with the "Code Sample" buttom, but it's seems unreadable. I don't sure if this because I am doing something wrong or because I don't have some permissions. Do I copy and paste the code to here or I need to do this in different way?

Comment: If you must, simply add a `space` in `" %c"` to consume the `'\n'` left in `stdin` by your last call to `scanf()` ... Otherwise, recommend all user-input be done with `fgets()` into a *sufficiently sized* buffer (character array), parse as needed with `sscanf()`, but in your case simply dereferencing the pointer or using `array[0]` will give you the first character.

Comment: See [stackoverflow markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to get a consistent style. For copy/paste code, there's also a button shortcut for code on most browsers.

Comment: Is the code ok right now?

Answer (score -1):

Your post doesn't clearly explain what you need. What I understood is, you need to read some input without pressing the enter key. If this is what you need help with, I've got you covered.

Let's say you are reading a single character from the keyboard without pressing the enter key.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char read_character() {
    system("/bin/stty raw");
    char trash=(getchar());
    system("/bin/stty cooked");
}
char continue_playing() {
    char choice = 'N';
    printf("Do you want to continue playing?(Y/N): ");
    choice = read_character();
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `system()` for that. It should be used before/after the program is run. Also, that works on Linux only.